# Django modelformset_factory adding one additional field

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have this scenario in which I am updating the data with model factory formset , the below code is working fine but the problem is that it is showing one additional field which is not needed in the end. Please see the below image
[image]

forms.py

```
class SupplyChainStopsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    is_supplier = forms.BooleanField(required=False,
                                     widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'style': 'width:20px;height:20px;'}))

    class Meta:
        model = SupplyChainStops
        exclude = ('ingredient',)

update_stop_formset_factory=modelformset_factory(SupplyChainStops,form=SupplyChainStopsForm)
```

template

```
<form method="POST" class="add-new-form edit-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.management_form }}
          {{ form }}
```

view

```
item = SupplyChainStops.objects.filter(ingredient__name=ingredient).all()
form = update_stop_formset_factory(queryset=item)
```

Answer (score 1):

modelformset_factory has a default value of 1 on the "extra" parameter:

```
def modelformset_factory(model, form=ModelForm, formfield_callback=None,
                         formset=BaseModelFormSet, extra=1, can_delete=False,
                         can_order=False, max_num=None, fields=None, exclude=None,
                         widgets=None, validate_max=False, localized_fields=None,
                         labels=None, help_texts=None, error_messages=None,
                         min_num=None, validate_min=False, field_classes=None,
                         absolute_max=None, can_delete_extra=True, renderer=None):
```

Set it to zero when you create the factory:

```
update_stop_formset_factory=modelformset_factory(SupplyChainStops,form=SupplyChainStopsForm, extra=0)
```

Comment: 'Had the same problem' is not an  answer, sorry.

Comment: I had the solution in there but I edited to be formatted as an answer

Comment: Yep adding extra=0 resolved my problem too.